# How is called use of duck typing

Tags: naming-conventions, terminology, duck-typing

How should I call process of using *duck typing*? What should I say "I'm performing duck typing" or "I'm checking if it's a duck:)".

*Duck checking* doesn't sounds good and *type checking* is just plain wrong name for it.

Comment: ... is this a programming question?

Comment: @Anonymous: Hahaha... no, I think he means [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Comment: Oh, I don't get all this programming theory crap.

Comment: I think you should say "I am quacking." and just get it over with. xD

Comment: By the way, for those wondering why it's called duck typing: the phrase originates from the sentence saying, "If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck."

Answer (score 2):

*I am using duck typing*, I would say. It's along the same kind of lines as '*I am using static typing*', though they are different things.

Answer (score 0):

I think context matters here, are we talking about inline comments or overall design documents?

For design documents I think it's quite reasonable to say *I am using duck typing*.

At a given point in the code I'm not sure that it's useful to say that. Consider, using some  fictional language

```
 function wibble(anObject) {

      // what do we say here? 
      anObject.computeMedianValue();

      anObject.render(device);
 }
```

First note that we don't actually check it's a duck, in the examples I see the code just goes

```
 obj.quack()
```

The program structure usually arranges that only things that can quack get passed down. I don't see many examples of

```
if (obj can quack )
  obj.quack()
else if ( obj can grunt)
  obj.grunt()
```

that wouldn't be very polymorphic, but even if we did want to check the capabilities we very much do not write code

```
if ( obj isA duck)
```

the whole idea of duck typing is that we consider the specific capabilities we need in the current context -  walk (like a duck) , quack (like a duck) - not "is it a duck?"

So in the code I would not particularly reference duck typing, any more than I sprinkle *I'm doing object orientation* around a standard Java program. The comment might say why you know that that object can compute a median, or what to do if it can't.

Answer (score 0):

Duck Typing

The name comes from the phrase:

> If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck,
>   then it probably is a duck.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_test

Which implies that if it has all the relevant attributes of a duck, why bother doing careful tests to check if it something other than a duck.

It may be something other than a duck, but most people won't care, because it is duck-like in those ways that matter right now.

Duck typing is similar in this way: Why bother controlling the type of parameters and variables in order to restrict what operations the user can perform.

It doesn't matter what types you pass to a function as long as the operations still work on whatever type it really is.

If you can add two types, who cares what number type they are?

If the object you pass to the `paginateResult()` function has a `query()`, and a `get_next_result()` method what does it matter what type it is?

In a statically typed language, the object would have to be a subclass of `queryResult` or implement a `paginates` interface.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing